# How do I pass integer parameters to an .Net MVC Restful service call?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, swagger

I'm writing a .Net WebApi MVC restful web service.
I am having issues passing parameters as integers and longs.

Here is a sample definition of an exposed service call.

```
[HttpGet("{sampleID}")]
public SummaryDataCounts Get(int sampleID) {}
```

I am using the open source tool Swagger as part of my solution.
When I debug through Visual Studio 17 (and Swagger test page), the results I expect. The input parameter is indeed an integer with the specified value.

To generate client side code, I'm using swagger-codegen-cli on the command line.
On the client side, it generates the expected prototypes along the expected parameter type (in this case "**int**").

Here is what my command line call looks like:

```
swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate^ --verbose^ --input-spec http://localhost:56995/swagger/v1/swagger.json^ --lang csharp^ --output output/SampleAPI
```

There are a couple of things I notice:

**1)** On the client side, my service method prototype looks like this:

```
SummaryDataCounts(int? sampleID)
```

Why is my parameter now a nullable integer?

**2)** When calling the method from my client (with a nullable integer parameter), the service always sees a parameter with a zero (0) value, no matter what number I pass in.

Why is this the case?
Is there something wrong with my method definition?

Thanks,JB

Comment: See if this is relevant: [C# Why does it make properties nullable?](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2885)

Comment: Helen:  Thanks for the tip. That seems about right. I guess I have decorate ALL my non-string class members and services parameters as required...

Comment: How do I decorate my parameters to be required on the server side?

Comment: Which library are you using to generate the Swagger spec? Swashbuckle?

Comment: Swashbuckle on the server to expose JSON interface and swagger (swagger-codegen-cli) to generate the client code.